# Cannot attach file upload to contact form email

Tags: asp.net, razor, webforms

I'm trying to create a simple contact form in which the user can fill in their details and also upload a file. Upon a form submission, the file will be attached to the contact email and also uploaded to a directory on my server. I've been following the .NET Web Forms documentation and I can send the emails and upload to my server fine, but with the attachment in the email it fails and I can't see why!

Here's my code, I get the message "Error 1" after the submission:

```
@{ 

var fileName = "";  

<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form">
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" />
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" />
    <input type="file" name="fileAttachment" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>

  if(IsPost) {
      var fileSavePath = "";
      var msg = "";        

      try{        
         var uploadedFile = Request.Files[0];
         fileName = Path.GetFileName(uploadedFile.FileName);
         fileSavePath = Server.MapPath("~/MyDirectory/" + fileName);

         if (uploadedFile.ContentLength > 1120000) {
             msg = "The maximum file size is 5 MB";
             <p>@msg</p>    
         }else{
             uploadedFile.SaveAs(fileSavePath);             

             var name = Request.Form["name"];
             var email = Request.Form["email"];
             var fileAttachment = Request["fileAttachment"];

             if( !name.IsEmpty() || !email.IsEmpty())
             {
                 string message = string.Format("Name: {0}<br/><br/>Email: {1}"
                    , name                           
                    , email  
                 );

                 try{
                         WebMail.SmtpServer = "127.0.0.1";
                         var filesList = new string [] { fileAttachment }; 
                         WebMail.Send(
                              from: "no-reply@mydomain.com",
                              to: "me@mydomain.com",
                              subject: "File attached",
                              body: message,
                              filesToAttach: filesList
                         );

                     }catch (Exception ex ){
                         <p>Error 1</p>
                     }
                 }                                   
             }

      }catch(HttpException ex){
            msg = "Error 2";
            <p>@msg</p>                   

      }                      
   }
}
```

Can anyone see why this isn't working?

Comment: I'd suggest actually examining the exception (for example, ex.Message) rather than simply ignoring it and outputting "Error 1" - that would probably tell you what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're attaching the raw content of the uploaded file:

```
var fileAttachment = Request["fileAttachment"];
...
var filesList = new string [] { fileAttachment }; 
WebMail.Send(
    from: "no-reply@mydomain.com",
    to: "me@mydomain.com",
    subject: "File attached",
    body: message,
    filesToAttach: filesList
);
```

The parameter `filesToAttach` takes a list of filenames, therefore you need to save your fileAttachment to a file first, then send it, and finally delete the file. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh414138(v=vs.111).aspx, specifically:

> filesToAttach
>   Type: System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<String>
>   (Optional) A collection of file names that specifies the files to
>   attach to the email message, or null if there are no files to attach.
>   The default value is null.

I should also note that the error handling you have in place is probably worse than not having any at all; you are actively hiding the error behind the phrases "Error 1" and "Error 2". If the `try ... catch` blocks had not been in place you may have been given meaningful error messages to work from.